# How to convert string containing array to array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have a string in Swift that contains an array in it. Is it possible to convert the string into an array? All I have found on the internet is converting `"abc"` to `["a","b","c"]`, which I would **not** like to do.
String: `"[\"value1\",\"value2\",\"value3\"]"`
Result: `["value1","value2","value3"]`

I am getting the string from a web request. The code for the request is here:

```
func webRequest(uri:String)->String{
        var value = "";
        let request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: uri)! as URL)
        do {
            let response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<URLResponse?>? = nil
            let data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returning: response)
            value = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!;
        } catch _ {

        }
        return value;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the string from? Can you show the code of how you get the string in the first place? That will help 

Comment: I am getting it from a web request to a server running PHP

Comment: "I have a string in Swift that contains an array in it." No you don't, well not really. You have a textual representation of multiple items, but it's neither valid Swift, nor valid JOSN (because of the single quotes)

Comment: Just as I thought. What you are doing is incorrectly parsing the web response into a string instead of an array. Can you show the code that deals with your web request?

Comment: This is what we call an XY Problem :-)

Comment: Most probably this *is* JSON (and the backslashes are artifacts from printing the string).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for adding that code. I’m guessing you got this from a tutorial or something because this is VERY old code. NSURLConnection hasn’t been the network class of choice for at least 4 or 5 years. Let me write an answer for you to update your code.

Comment: @MartinR I agree. The JSON backslashes were edited in after the comment though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First off, the problem here is not converting your string into an array. The problem is getting the array from the web request in the first place.

Let me update your web request function.

```
func webRequest(url: URL, completion: ([String]?) -> () { // I have updated this function to be asynchronous
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        data, urlResponse, error in

        // you might want to add more code in here to check the data is valid etc...

        guard let data = data,
              let arrayOfStrings = JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data) else {
            // something went wrong getting the array of strings so return nil here...
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        completion(arrayOfStrings)
    }

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Using this code instead of the code in your question you now have an asynchronous function that will not block the app and one that will pass your array of strings into the completion.

You can now run it like this...

```
webRequest(url: someURL) { strings in
    guard let strings = strings else {
        // strings is nil because something went wrong with the web request
        return
    }

    print(strings)
}
```

**Creating the URL**

In your question you have this code... `NSURL(string: someString)! as URL`

You can change this to... `let url = URL(string: someString)`

**Quick side note**

Careful where you find tutorials and using code you find on the web. The code used in this question is very old. (at least 4 or 5 years "out of date").

If you're looking for tutorials to help with Swift then some recommendations are...

- [Ray Wenderlich](https://raywenderlich.com)
- [Hacking with swift](https://hackingwithswift.com)